# Project Euler #2: sum of even Fibonacci numbers, using generators

Tags: python, programming-challenge, fibonacci-sequence, generator

I am currently working on Project Euler problem #2 which requires you to print the **sum** of all **even** fibonacci numbers below 4 million.

I just recently learned about generators and from my understanding they are used to decrease memory consumption by generating values on the fly (and not storing them in a huge list).

Does this still work when used in a `for` loop or will it just generate all values, store them in a list and then loop through them?

```
for n in some_generator(): pass
```

In my specific case the code looks like this:

```
def fibonacci(n): # yields all fibonacci numbers below n
    second_last_n = 0
    last_n = 1
    while (last_n < n):
        current_n = second_last_n + last_n
        second_last_n = last_n
        last_n = current_n
        yield current_n

def filter_even(nums): # yields all numbers in nums (a generator) which are even
    for n in nums:
        if (n % 2 == 0):
            yield n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's weird that the `fibonacci()` generates a sequence that starts with 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ….  Conventionally, the Fibonacci sequence starts with either 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, … or 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ….

A purer approach would be to use [`itertools.takewhile()`] in conjunction with an infinite generator.

You should also take advantage of parallel assignment.

The `fibonacci()` generator would look like this:

```
def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```

`filter_even()` is fine.  You could also just write a generator expression instead.

```
from itertools import takewhile

print(sum(n for n in takewhile(lambda n: n < 4000000, fibonacci()) if n % 2 == 0))
```

Comment: _...The comment # yields all fibonacci numbers below n is misleading...._ sorry, I just fixed the code to use a while loop instead of a for loop, so the comment should be right..

Comment: In the future, please refrain from modifying code in the question after posting.